# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react.

i am facing following issue while trying to build a functional component:
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call.
Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {render} from "react-dom";

const functionVersion = ()=>{
    const [name, setName] = useState("name");

    return(
        <div>     
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>       
            <input
             id="name"
             value={name}
             onChange= {e=>setName(e.target.value)}
             >
            </input>
        </div>
    )
}

render(functionVersion(), document.getElementById("root"))
```

may i know what is wrong with my hooks syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use Hooks inside components.

Functional components are also a function, so still can call then as a normal function, but if you do that, it wont be a react component.

To render a functional component, you need to use `JSX` that will be converted to `React.createElement(...)`.

Change:

```
render(functionVersion(), document.getElementById("root"))
```

to:

```
render(<FunctionVersion/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

You also need to make the name of the functional component with the first letter in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

```
const FunctionVersion = ()=>{
    const [name, setName] = useState("name");

    return(
        <div>     
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>       
            <input
             id="name"
             value={name}
             onChange= {e=>setName(e.target.value)}
             >
            </input>
        </div>
    )
}

render(<FunctionVersion/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```